# Java 2 dimensional integer array check existence

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a two dimensional array in java. Here I want to check the existence of a pair of values. But I got false all the time.

```
int[][] test_use = new int[1][2];
test_use[0][0] = 2;
test_use[0][1] = 6;
int[][] constraints = new int[1][2];
constraints[0][0] = 2;
constraints[0][1] = 6;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(constraints).contains(test_use));
```

Do you guys have any ideas for this issue? How could I check its existence properly. Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks to me like you're checking if the array 'test_use' is in the 'contraints' array, which it isn't. Maybe you should see if it contains the values inside 'test_use'.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy yes, but how to check the 2d Array has the element of {2,6}? Maybe I should give up by using for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like this, defined in a class of your preference:

```
public bool contains(int[][] container, int[][] isContained){
 bool miss = false;
 for(int i = 0; i < isContained.length && !miss; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < isContained[i].length && !miss; j++){
        if(container.length > i && container[i].length > j){
            if(container[i][j] == isContained[i][j]) {
               continue;
            }
        }
        miss = true;
     }
 }

 return !miss;

}
```

Comment: thanks, I need to conquer my laziness to write this method. :)

Answer (score 1):

The contains() method on Java collections uses the equals() method on each contained object, to check whether the comparison object is contained.

The equals method for an array just inherits from Object, which compares whether the objects are the same object, rather than whether they are logically-equivalent.

You are creating 2 different arrays and comparing them with equals() and they are not the same object, so their equals method is returning false, so contains returns false.

As such, this prints false too:

```
System.out.println(new int[]{i,j}.equals(new int[]{i,j}));
```

If you want to get the right result, you can implement the comparison yourself:

```
int[][] arr = new int[1][2];
arr[0] = new int[]{2,6};
List<int[]> l = Arrays.asList(arr);
for (int[] check : l) {
    if(check[0] == 2 && check[1] == 6) {
        System.out.println(true);
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println(false);
```

Comment: thank you. it's a good and deep explanation about contains() and equals().

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you what you want.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(constraints).contains(test_use[0][1]));
```